# module 'sib_api_v3_sdk' has no attribute 'SMTPApi'

Tags: python, sendinblue

I am trying send a email with sendinblue but i have the problem "module 'sib_api_v3_sdk' has no attribute 'SMTPApi'".

I installed sib_api_v3_sdk with pip and i use python 3.8.5

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Configure API key authorization: api-key
configuration = sib_api_v3_sdk.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['api-key'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

# Uncomment below lines to configure API key authorization using: partner-key
# configuration = sib_api_v3_sdk.Configuration()
# configuration.api_key['partner-key'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.SMTPApi(sib_api_v3_sdk.ApiClient(configuration))
send_smtp_email = sib_api_v3_sdk.SendSmtpEmail(to=[{"email":"testmail@example.com","name":"John Doe"}], template_id=56, params={"name": "John", "surname": "Doe"}, headers={"X-Mailin-custom": "custom_header_1:custom_value_1|custom_header_2:custom_value_2|custom_header_3:custom_value_3", "charset": "iso-8859-1"}) # SendSmtpEmail | Values to send a transactional email

try:
    # Send a transactional email
    api_response = api_instance.send_transac_email(send_smtp_email)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling SMTPApi->send_transac_email: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: This is example code in my real code i add my 'api_key'

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you update the package to the latest version and use the below code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

configuration = sib_api_v3_sdk.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['api-key'] = 'YOUR API KEY'

api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.TransactionalEmailsApi(sib_api_v3_sdk.ApiClient(configuration))
subject = "My Subject"
html_content = "<html><body><h1>This is my first transactional email </h1></body></html>"
sender = {"name":"John Doe","email":"example@example.com"}
to = [{"email":"example@example.com","name":"Jane Doe"}]
cc = [{"email":"example2@example2.com","name":"Janice Doe"}]
bcc = [{"name":"John Doe","email":"example@example.com"}]
reply_to = {"email":"replyto@domain.com","name":"John Doe"}
headers = {"Some-Custom-Name":"unique-id-1234"}
params = {"parameter":"My param value","subject":"New Subject"}
send_smtp_email = sib_api_v3_sdk.SendSmtpEmail(to=to, bcc=bcc, cc=cc, reply_to=reply_to, headers=headers, html_content=html_content, sender=sender, subject=subject)

try:
    api_response = api_instance.send_transac_email(send_smtp_email)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling SMTPApi->send_transac_email: %s\n" % e)
```

You can find more examples at https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#sendtransacemail